# only first value is accessible in range of value returned by php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have php function which retrieve users information from database and set them in 5 variables. 4 of them are visible and one of them is hidden. when I run the function, list of users is display correctly. And I want to access the hidden variable with jquery on click event, (to test jquery work fine I try to alert the value of hidden variable) but when I click on each user in list it display the value of hidden variable which is belong to the first user in the list.

there is my php code (only the important part):

```
$contacts->bind_result($contactID, $name, $lastName, $photo, $emotion);
while($contacts->fetch())
{
    $this->setContactID($contactID);
    $this->setName($name);
    $this->setlastName($lastName);
    $this->setPhoto($photo);
    $this->setEmotion($emotion);
    ?>
        <!-- this part display photo, name and last name and emotion of contacts. -->

        <div style="height:60px">
            <div style='margin-top:5px; margin-right:5px; display:inline; float:left'>
               <?php echo "<img src=.." ,$this->getPhoto()," height='45' width='45' />" ?>
            </div>                 
            <div style="display:table; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px">
               <?php echo $this->getName() . "  " . $this->getlastName(); ?>
            </div>
            <div style="display:table">
               <?php echo $this->getEmotion(); ?>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" class="contId" value="<?php echo $this->getContactID(); ?>" />
        </div>

    <?php

}
```

I use (.load) function in jquery to load this php function in a div with (contacts) id in my html and also I use jquery ui in this div to make each user in list selectable. and I want to access each user hidden value when they are selected in list.

and this is my Jquery code:

```
$("#contacts").load("displayContact.php");

$("#contacts").selectable({
    selected:function(){alert ($(".contId").val());}
    });
```

Comment: This happens because you have `5` divs with `.contId` class. So you get the value of a first one. Clarify which one of this five you want to select.

Comment: there isn't any div with `.contId` class its only an `input` with this class and i want to select that `input` value which user click on it.

Comment: In a click handler, `$(this)` will be the element you clicked on. You can then use DOM traversal methods to find related elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take advantage of the callback events. This is what I would do:

```
$("#contacts").selectable({
    selected: function (event, ui) {
        var id = $(ui.selected).find(".contId").val();
        alert(id);
    }
});
```

***source:*** http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/

Comment: awesome, im glad I was able to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are trying to get the value of the hidden field contained in the division you are selecting, you can achieve this using the following code.

```
    $("#contents").selectable({
        selected : function(event, ui) {
           var contactId = $(ui.selected).find('.contId').eq(0).val();
           alert(contactId); 
       }
    });
```

According to the [jqueryUI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected), the selected event handler gets two arguments, the second of which is the element being selected. From that we just find the element with "contId" class, and get the value of the first element (only one in your case).

I hope this helps and Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

try this, (not tested, hope it works)

```
$("#contacts").selectable({
    selected:function(event, ui){ 
        alert ($( ui.selected ).closest( ".contId" ).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: when I try this code its result become **undefined**

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned the problem is that you have **5** (not divs, ok), but input fields with the same class `contId`. So, clicking on each you want to see the value of a clicked one.

As I see in a docs, for a `selected` attribute you can have 2 arguments: `event` and `ui`. And you have property `selected` which holds your selected element. I think you should define `selectable` like this:

```
$("#contacts").selectable({
    selected:function(event, ui){ 
        alert ($( ui.selected ).find( ".contId" ).val());
    }
});
```

What we do here is:

1. Get a clicked object and turn it into jquery object: `$( ui.selected )`
2. Find in this clicked object an element with class `contId`: `find( ".contId" )`
3. Get it's value: `val()`.

Comment: thank you very much, your description help me to understand better how this function work. and i'm sorry that I didn't catch your question correctly.